# Simulating Asset Prices by Independently Simulating Supply and Demand

Tags: pricing, simulations, market-microstructure, economics, commodities

If I have an asset, whose supply is generally mean-reverting and whose demand is generally cyclical, could I somehow simulate / project the supply and demand levels across multiple discrete time periods into the future and then calculate a price for the asset at each period?

How would that best be accomplished?